# Which timezone to use for all users aroung the world?

Tags: reactjs, django

Right now I am using UTC as timezone. But I am staying in Bangladesh and It is ahead of 6 hours from server time. I am using a clock as UTC timezone it is also showing me time ahead of 6 hours.

```
<Clock format={'HH:mm:ss'} ticking={true} timezone={'UTC'} />
```

Here, I want global timezone. I am in Bangladesh so I will see the bd time, if I am in Russia, then I will see time according to russia. so which timezone to use for that?

Comment: Your server does not know where the client is located.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the client's time zone (and offset) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-time-zone-and-offset-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Intl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) object of the internationalization API to get the local zone string

```
const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
```

Comment: Thank you! It is working now. Now how to convert django TIME_ZONE = 'UTC' to the same way.

Comment: My general recommendation is: store in database and serve with the API using UTC always, then convert to local timezone in the client side app.